# Database Records Sorting

Tags: database, sorting

Is there any query that would go n sort records in the data-base via any column. I don't want the a "Ordered Result". I want the stored records rearranged and sorted.

Comment: Can you expand on this - I don't really understand.  You want a query that will sort on any column that you pass to it?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how databases work. You don't get control over how the database stores its data, and that's a good thing too.

Comment: @Carl. Yes, but he seems confident enough to vote down what seems to be a reasonable alternative (to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not possible.........

Comment: the brain surgen who down voted could please give a possible soluion